# Did ICS stop supporting clicking a number in text to dial?

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, phone-app

I used to be able to click a number inside text (email or web page) to dial it. After upgrading to ics this feature seems to have been removed. Is that so? Any way to get it back?

UPDATE: it seems to work with US phone numbers, but not ones that are used in my country (Israel). Can it be that my carrier forgot to update the pattern for recognizing numbers as phone numbers?

Comment: Is it HTC's phone?

Comment: it's a galaxy s2

Answer (score 1):

As @roxan seemed to be indicating, there is a legal suit against HTC in which Apple claimed a patent on this [ability to convert clicking on phone numbers and email addresses into actionable links on smartphones](http://www.fiercewireless.com/story/apple-opens-new-patent-fights-htc-samsung/2012-06-07).

[This December 2011 article](http://www.sfgate.com/cgi-bin/article.cgi?f=/c/a/2011/12/21/BU5H1MFCVG.DTL) says:

> Apple also has civil patent infringement cases against HTC and
>   Samsung. Both Asian rivals have also filed their own retaliatory
>   actions to the ITC and in U.S courts

and [this article](http://www.pcworld.com/article/249824/apple_files_another_us_patent_suit_against_samsung.html) indicates Apple opened four lawsuits (as of February 2012) against Samsung for patent infringement, including the ability to make phone numbers clickable.

So it looks as if other manufacturers may be rolling back this feature early, for fear of Apple's patent troll tearing down their towns and eating their goats (and your ability to click phone numbers).