# Software recognizing phone numbers in documents?

Tags: applications, calls, touchscreen, phone-app, ios

On an iphone I've seen a docx file with some phone numbers in it which you could call by just touching them. Is there any android software doing this?

There is [a question here](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/24146/did-ics-stop-supporting-clicking-a-number-in-text-to-dial) which seemingly implies that apple holds a patent on this feature, but I am still asking in case they allowed somebody to use it with android...

P.S. Answers to [another question](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/58732/clickable-phone-numbers-on-a-wifi-only-tablet) mention some apps which enable you to call a number from a text file **once you have copied it**; I would prefer to avoid that extra action...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried Google's [Quickoffice](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.quickoffice.android)? It detects numbers (and underlining them), and lets you click the number to open the dialer with that number.

Comment: Wow, perfect! Thank you very much! I tried several apps with no avail, how come I did not look at this from the very beginning?!